# Apache mod_rewrite craziness in inheritance

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have some crazy strangeness in mod_rewrites being ignored when child directories also have an htaccess file (regardless of whether the file has a conflicting rule or not).

So example to redirect /index.html of a dir to / for canonical purposes...

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1/[R=301,L]
```

So... if this is set in the root settings, then everything works. But once a child directory has an htaccess of its own (even without a conflicting rewrite) it just completely ignores.

Comment: I remember having such a problem in the past. I can't remember if I ever managed to fix that problem. One way to go about it would be by bypassing all .htaccess files and directly editing httpd.conf.

Answer (score 5):

By default, child htaccess files do **not** *inherit* parent rules.

You'll need to add this line in each child htaccess files

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

or, even better (if you want parent rules to be applied before child ones)

```
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
```

Comment: Going to give this a go and I'll post back with our results. Thanks!

Comment: Going to select as a "correct answer" considering its "correct-ness" but I think we may have some extraneous issues. I have not forgotten your help though and definitely appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to post another question if you face issues again

Comment: "but I think we may have some extraneous issues." - An additional _complexity_ with mod_rewrite inheritance is that the directives are essentially copied in-place, so if you have directives that are reliant on the directory-prefix in the parent config, then they may not work as-is in the child config.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **more than one** subfolders with .htaccess files and you need all of them to inherit parent rule - use in parent .htaccess file:

```
RewriteOptions InheritDown
```

instead of typing "RewriteOptions Inherit" in every child .htaccess.

If you need the rules from the parent scope to be applied **before** rules specified in any child's scope use:

```
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore
```